# Solving android SDK "failed to parse output of adb version"

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I've run into the "**failed to parse output of adb version**"... i done it before and managed somehow to make it work again, but this time all my efforts were in vain. 
So please help!!!

I've tried:

- closing the adb process from taskmanager or by cmd, by "adb kill-server" and restarting eclipse ... + other variations
- re-installed a fresh Eclipse 3.7 and the latest android-sdk-r13 ...
- did a "netstat -o" (some forums mention this... to see if my 5537 is used by another process...)

Basically I can't connect Eclipse to a emulator. 
My latest triumph: by cmd "adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555" and it says "connected to 127.0.0.1:5555" but obviously I'm NOT! But I've noticed that after this command, for 1-2 fractions of a second, the emulator appears in devices tab in DDMS perspective, but just for 1-2 fractions of a second, with a "offline" tag... Oh yeah, i use a virtual machine in Virtual Box (I use NAT+PCFASTIII + port forwarding on 5555, witch means it should work, but it doesn't), also tried with the classic emulator ... same result.
- also when i do the "adb start-server" it starts it on 5537 (as expected)

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: wow! Thank you guys for editing my question title & content. Thank you. I managed to make it work again. What i did is added port forwarding for my Virtual Box machine for port 5554 (i already had it for port 5555) and it works now. It still has bogus sens for me, but works.

Comment: Can you add your solution to this as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry Bill...

I managed to make it work again. What i did is added port forwarding for my Virtual Box machine for port 5554 (i already had it for port 5555) and it works now. It still has bogus sens for me, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. My firewall was blocking adb, so making it "trusted application" solves it.